# How to connect local redis to docker container using docker compose

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I am facing an issue with connect local redis with docker container, this is my docker compose file.

```
version: "3"

services:
  test:
    build: .
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: nodemon --delay 6 index.js
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/test
    ports:
      - "5007:5007"
    links:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: qbo_redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

But it is not working.

Getting error

```
bash
TI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"3ed84a23c52d\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

If i remove the redis entries from docker-compose.yml file, its working without any error.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: Getting error on "docker exec -it $(docker ps -q)  bash" command :"TI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"3ed84a23c52d\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown"

Comment: @trinath Please edit your question and add this detail – as it's written, it sounds like your `docker-compose up` command is failing, not some other command.

Comment: @trinath Your error occurs because the `docker ps -q` returns the IDs of two containers. If you run only one service, the `docker ps -q` will return one ID.

Answer (score 0):

`docker ps -q` returns a list of containers and cannot be used to access the shell. Use `docker ps -ql` to work with the last container created.

`redis` images don't contain Bash. They're based on Alpine Linux, but can you use `/bin/sh`. Try this way:

```
 docker exec -it qbo_redis /bin/sh
```

or

```
 docker exec -it $(docker ps -ql) /bin/sh
```